# How to retrieve image from mongodb grid_fs using carrierwave

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, carrierwave, gridfs

In my rails application I am uploading image using carrierwave to mongoid grid_fs. I am using my remote system "192.xxx.xx.xx" as my mongodb server. While retrieving image is not displayed. If i use my local system as mongodb then its displaying fine.

Comment: Please post the error, the code you've tried implementing.

Comment: I didn't get any error. Its displaying the image name in the image tag. If application and mongoDb runs in the same system image displaying perfectly. If I use mongoDb in romote system that time image, audio and video files only not displaying.